# Help in deriving the Adler-Bell-Jackiw anomaly

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-anomalies

I'm stuck on the derivation of the [Adler-Bell-Jackiw anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_anomaly#An_example%3a_baryonic_charge_non-conservation). This is discussed on page 666 of Peskin and Schroeder (equation 19.76) or [these notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0509097) on page 14 (equation 39).

According to these sources, we can evaluate a matrix element as:
\begin{equation}
\langle x | e^{-\partial^2/M^2} | x \rangle = \displaystyle\lim_{x \to y} \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^4 k}{(2\pi)^4} e^{-ik \cdot (x-y)} e^{k^2/M^2}
\end{equation}
where $M$ is a regularizer. Maybe this equation is really trivial, but I'm completely lost and would really like some help.

What I've tried so far is inserting momentum eigenstates:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\langle x | e^{-\partial^2/M^2} | x \rangle & = \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^4 p}{(2 \pi)^4} \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \;  \langle x |p \rangle \langle p | e^{-\partial^2/M^2}|k \rangle \langle k | x \rangle \\&
= \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^4 p}{(2 \pi)^4} \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \; e^{ix \cdot (p-k) } \langle p | e^{-\partial^2/M^2}|k \rangle \\&
= \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^4 p}{(2 \pi)^4} \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \;  e^{ix \cdot (p-k) }  e^{k^2/M^2} \delta^4(p-k)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I have no idea if I'm even on the right track, or the above is complete nonsense. Any help is much appreciated.

In response to Adam's comment:

The reason why I wasn't sure about what I've done was the $\lim_{x \to y}$ part. Is there any reason why we would evaluate it as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\displaystyle\lim_{x \to y} \langle y | e^{-\partial^2/M^2} | x \rangle & = \displaystyle\lim_{x \to y} \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \;  \langle y | e^{-\partial^2/M^2}|k \rangle \langle k | x \rangle \\&
= \displaystyle\lim_{x \to y} \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \; e^{k^2/M^2} e^{i k \cdot (y-x)} \\&
= \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \; e^{k^2/M^2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Whereas we could also evaluate it as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\langle x | e^{-\partial^2/M^2} | x \rangle & = \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \;  \langle x | e^{-\partial^2/M^2}|k \rangle \langle k | x \rangle \\&
= \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \; e^{k^2/M^2} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
which seems to give the same result and is a simpler method. Why do most sources seem to use the first approach rather then the second?

Comment: That looks good to me, though you should look at the matrix element $\lim_{x\to y}\langle x|\cdots|y\rangle$ and you don't need to insert the identity twice.

Comment: @Adam thank you! Your method does indeed get the right answer, but it has sparked another question. Could you look at my edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove brackets $|k \rangle\langle k|$ into the second method which you've reprsesented because there is $e^{\frac{k^{2}}{M^{2}}}$ term; you have to make a summation over all $k$, which is completely equivalent to the first method (note also that $|k\rangle $ doesn't coincide with integration variable $k$)